# How to decrease margin in the add_gridspec subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, subplot

I tried to use seaborn, matplotlib, and add_gridspec to display multiple plots in one figure using seaborn. I created subplots using gridspec and drew the plots inside the subplots. However, I encountered an issue where there is a gap between the main plot and the density plot in the right panel. I want to reduce this gap.

**Here is my code (EXAMPLE CODE) :**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))

widths = [4, 1, 4, 1]
heights = [1, 4]

### Gridspec preparation
spec = fig.add_gridspec(ncols=4, nrows=2, width_ratios=widths, height_ratios=heights)

### Setting axes
axs = {}
for i in range(len(heights)*len(widths)):
    axs[i] = fig.add_subplot(spec[i//len(widths), i%len(widths)])
    axs[i].text(0.5, 0.5, f"axs[{i}]", fontdict=dict(ha="center", color="k", fontsize=20))

### **I guess that this part creates the problem**
for i,a in enumerate([axs[4], axs[6]]):
    #######
    a.set_ylabel("GAP CREATOR?", fontsize=20)
    a.tick_params(length=20, width=2, labelsize=20, direction="in", which="major")
    #######
    a.grid(ls="--")
fig.tight_layout()
```

I tried to identify which part of the code affects the gap between the plots. I found that some parts of the code affect the gap. I have marked the code that I believe is causing the issue with comments (###########) in the example code.

It seems that the gap is widening due to the addition of labels and adjustments to the tick_label font sizes. However, even without that particular code, there is still a noticeable gap that is uncomfortable. I was looking for a solution to this problem but wasn't sure which keywords to search for.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think the problem may be due to the two axes that are created, but not used (i.e. `axs[1]` and `axs[3]`). You turn them off in step 5, but their space is still created, which is what is causing the gaps from what I can tell. Try refactoring to remove the creation of those two, unnecessary axes. That may fix the problem. There are other possible work arounds, but they are more difficult to implement with the current axes config.

Comment: When creating subplots, matplotlib reserves some default space for the x and y tick labels.  This spacing doesn't take into account that some subplots don't have y tick labels. `tight_layout` also seems to assume you want the same horizontal distances between the subplots while leaving the same space for the y-labels of each of the subplots. (You could provide some dummy test data, e.g. via `np.random.randn(100,100)` to make your code easier to reproduce for others.)  The trickiness of nicely combining subplots is one of the reasons why seaborn doesn't support this out-of-the-box.

Comment: A trick that seems to work somewhat for your case, is temporarily disabling the y-axis of `axs[6]`, calling `tight_layout()` and enabling that y-axis again. So `axs[6].yaxis.set_visible(False); fig.tight_layout(); axs[6].yaxis.set_visible(True)`. Still further adjustments could be done by, at the very end of the code, get the location of the axes and set them again, moving them a bit.

Comment: Seems like it would be far easier to plot two [`sns.jointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) or [`sns.JointGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.JointGrid.html)

Comment: Code modification was carried out. SSCCE guidelines were considered. @Trenton McKinney

Comment: I succeeded in correcting the code to eliminate the inconvenient gap! Here is how to adjust the gap: ```fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = -1.7)```. I just apply a code, and then I could get a very fantastic figure! I don't know how this code worked, but the results are good!